# Is it possible to be socialist, liberal, and conservative like this candidate to president of Perú claims?

Tags: socialism, conservatism, liberalism

Candidate to president of Perú Hernando de Soto claims to be "socialist, liberal and conservative". I can't find a possible definition of the 3 terms for them to coexist together. To me, modern liberalism or left liberalism seems similar to socialism, but it is contradictory with conservativism. Classical liberalism seems similar to conservativism, I've seen conservatives claiming to be classical liberals in the economic sense, but it is contradictory to socialism. I guess you could be conservative in the cultural aspect and socialist in the economic aspect, but it seems to me that depending of the type of liberalism you choose there is always going to be a conflict with liberalism.

Is it possible to be socialist, liberal, and conservative like Hernando de Soto claims to be?

Comment: if your countrie is already socialist and liberal then being socialist and liberal make you conservative as well. (I do not know how that apply to Peru)

Comment: I would assume that this candidate's political directions differ from issue to issue. It is perfectly possible to be conservative on one issue and liberal on another. Do you have a link to his election manifesto?

Comment: You seem to be talking about the [Avanza País](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_on_Country_-_Social_Integration_Party) candidate... who seems to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hernando_de_Soto_(economist) Since the party at least is very marginal in terms of vote share... such parties often claim all sorts of (possibly contradictory) things nobody pays much attention to.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the party claims "they are not interested in ideology", which is of course another weird statement from a political party, but probably explains some of the other statements. Also  de Soto seems to have run for presidency previously with other obscure shell parties, so it's probably just a personal vehicle for him.

Comment: Anyhow, from his rather lengthy Wikipedia bio, there's not much in the way of clear political positions other than he seems to support some kind of (more formal) property rights for the poor, which isn't much to go on to peg a political platform.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to have beliefs from different and opposing political ideologies?

Comment: Well, it's politics you know... It's not math that there are solid definitions of things that could not be changed no matter what (even in math it's not like this)... You can claim anything and you can be anything you want in terms of your politics view... But what are you going to do in practice? That has nothing to do with these buzz words...

Comment: Given his background, he seem to trying to pull off some kind of LRM (France) movement, which claims to be centrist, but it's more neoliberal than anything else.

Comment: "Conservative' is a variable.  It's perfectly possible to be socially liberal but economically conservative, or vice versa.

Comment: de Soto's [main thesis](https://wiki.mises.org/wiki/The_Mystery_of_Capital:_Why_Capitalism_Triumphs_in_the_West_and_Fails_Everywhere_Else) is that the life of poor people in poor countries can be bettered by giving them stable property rights rather than having them squat on land/buildings that they do not own.  this would allow for example borrowing using those properties as collateral.  this is pretty classical economics, with a social improvement goal.  So these are 2 usually somewhat opposite political aims in the economic sphere, coexisting.  As to adding social conservatism, why not?

Comment: note that a lot of conservatives have lately started calling themselves liberals since they want to liberate the market from the clutches of the evil big government